# JSON Request using AFNetworking 2 giving me a NSURLErrorDomain error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nserror

I am making a simple `GET` request using `AFNetworking 2`, but I am getting a `NSURLErrorDomain` error.

I created a manager class which subclasses `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and creates a singleton instance so that I can use a shared manager.

```
+ (id)manager {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];

    });
    return _sharedObject;
}


- (id)init {

    NSURL *baseURL = [ZSSAuthentication baseURL];
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    if (self) {

        [self setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
        [self setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
        [self.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:[ZSSAuthentication username] password:[ZSSAuthentication password]];

        [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)getData:(NSString *)pubID parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *results))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {


    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data/all/%@", pubID];
    [self GET:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // Check to see if there are errors
        ZSSError *error = [self errorForAPICall:responseObject status:[operation.response statusCode]];
        if (error) {
            [self logMessage:error.localizedDescription];
            failure(error);
            return;
        }

        NSDictionary *data = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
        completion(data);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failure(error);
    }];

}
```

Then, in my `viewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method I make a call to that method:

```
[[ZSSManager manager] getData:self.pubID parameters:nil completion:^(NSDictionary *results) {
        self.items = results;
        [self dataWillReload];
        NSLog(@"%@", results);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %li", error, (long)error.code);
    }];
```

Then I get this error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x7ff952306610 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://test.mysite.com/v1/data/all/5}
```

The strange thing is, on a previous `viewController`, I make a different call to the manager, and it completes and returns data correctly. But, when I make this second call, I get the error. AND, if I move that `getData` call out of the `viewDidLoad` method, and invoke it with a button press, it DOES WORK. What the heck?

What could be causing this?

Comment: Error code -999 in `NSURLErrorDomain` is `NSURLErrorCancelled`: "The connection was cancelled." This could be caused by a failed authentication challenge.

Comment: @mattt - But why would this only happen in `viewDidLoad` and not when I invoke the method with a button tap? Strange.

Comment: Are you running this in the simulator? If so, restart the simulator and see if it's still happening.

Comment: @remus - Yeah, in Simulator. But restarting or resetting didn't help. So strange that it only happens in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: It may simply be that it's not instantiated by that time. What happens if you put it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: @remus - That worked. But what wouldn't get instantiated by that time? The manager class? That is already created. AND, this worked fine in `viewDidLoad` in many other occasions when building this app.

Comment: Very likely the manager class - since it's a singleton, you may have already instantiated it elsewhere (the times it's working) whereas here, maybe not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65174/discussion-between-nic-hubbard-and-remus).

Comment: @NicHubbard did you ever figure what was the root cause? running into something similar.

Comment: @chourobin - Nope. I had to add some `dispatch_after` code and it seemed to solve the problem. Strange.